# Android emulator not connecting with internet

Tags: android, emulation

I have updated latest SDK upto 4.0 in android and install ADT pluging 18.0.0. But after installation of this am not able to connect with internet. I need to set somethin else. even i have restarted my adb, created new AVD and some other also. but i dont understand what is the problem for this. Please help me for this

Comment: try to delete the faulty AVD and create an other one.

Comment: Thanks for reply,But actually i have tried both the things but still its showing problem